# How to access camera from InAppBrowser?

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, inappbrowser

I am building a Hybrid application for Android and IOS using phonegap version 2.7.

In that I have display an external webpage, so inappbrowser is implemented to display.

Now, how can I invoke camera[navigator.camera.getPicture()] from inappbrowser.

Help me with a solution or if any workaround is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see the phone gap examples

Comment: @Ali Imran, Thanks for suggestion. Can you help me to use camera in InAppBrowser and if you can share the link that would be great.